# Cant reinstall mysql server in linux

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am completely new to Linux and I am stuck with this error form sometime now.
I uninstalled MySQL, and the next time i tried installing i  am getting the following error

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**

I tried installing the dependency separately but it did not work[image: Actual error snip]

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this issue?

Comment: Nope. Finally I decided to reinstall KDE, after that I could install MySql.